# Ubuntu 22.04.3 automatic downloads before log-in has a chance to cause unforeseen bugs?

Tags: boot, updates, 22.04, login, update-manager

Edit: The point of the post I suppose is to let devs know if a similar chain of events (starting downloads before log-in has happened) has the potential to cause issues. As for my personal issue I will reinstall Ubuntu and I guess I was lucky I didn't have anything important yet saved on the disks.

So I'm dual booting and I notice sometimes when I accidentally start Ubuntu (let startup process run itself) that even before I have logged in there's some downloads etc. happening in the background in the login screen.

Sometimes when I realize I accidentally started Ubuntu I just restart and navigate to Windows again. A) will this restarting potentially cause errors in the Ubuntu update process?

After the above had happened a few times, I manually started the update process inside the operating system, having logged in and all that.

That is when I got **(picture 1 Started Fingerprint Authentication ..Daemon? perhaps)** happen and it stayed like this for 2-3min until I decided to push restart. [image: Picture 1, the layout is all weird and the startup hang for like 2-3 minutes on the last part when I decided to press restart]

After restarting I'm stuck in[image: Previously not seen login screen, Personal issue: can't remember login since previously it had happened with press of Enter, but that is an personal issue I understand.]

Is it likely something broke? I can't remember login details so is reinstall/repair-install the only viable solution here or is there a magic button etc. that will help me proceed? Or any other way I could maybe try fix this issue ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @user535733 however I think instead of spending hours learning/navigating GRUB menu which I will forget a few days after reading about it all, I will just instead plug in a USB, reinstall the Ubuntu and be done with it.